# How to load a file and look at it's contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to find the answer to this on my own but have come up short.

Using JS/Jquery in html file, I need to:

1. When a link is pressed it loads a file located on the server.
2. Search the file for word x
3. If that word doesn't appear or appears only once, do nothing. If it appears 2 or more times open y url.

For now I can't even properly load a file as a variable.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
var myvar = $.get("localhost/readme.txt").responseText; 
document.write(myvar);
```

Comment: I'm still trying to load the file. I've tried var myvar = $.get("http://localhost/readme.txt").responseText;
document.write(myvar); and something similar but using the "load" function.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but you probably need an http:// before your localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, you just weren't accessing the responseText properly. Also, don't use `document.write()` to output test data, use the console.

```
$.get("localhost/readme.txt").done(function(filecontents) {
    console.log(filecontents);
    // now you can search through filecontents as plain text.
    if (filecontents.match(/myword/ig).length >= 2) {
        alert("DO STUFF!");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

No longer applies to question following edit...

---

You can't access a client's file system via Javascript - see

[Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

for more details.

There is some limited support coming with the HTML 5 implementation, but this might not suit for your needs:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: by local I meant a file on the server, not on the clients computer, sorry for the mistake, i've edited the post above.

Comment: From the documentation at your link "Load data from the *server* and place the returned HTML into the matched element.".  Loads data from the remote server, not the client.

Comment: I know. That's what I need my script to do.